# How to make the MS Identity SPA example work for organization and personal accounts

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I am following [this link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnetcore-webapi) to make my own project.

My project has

1. Reactjs
2. Asp.Net Core Web Api

to access user's emails from Hotmail.The Reactjs app and WebApi live on different servers.

The example is almost what I need, but it only accepts accounts within same organization, not accepts Personal accounts.

I thought I only need to change the Tenant ID from a specific ID to "common" in related configurations and it will work.
I also registered the Supported account types on Azure for both Web Api and Reactjs to use the

AnyOrg + Personal Account
[image]

[image]

here is the config for Angular

```
{
  "auth": {
    "clientId": "28xxx12",
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
    "validateAuthority": true,
    "redirectUri": "http://localhost:4200",
    "postLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:44321/signout-oidc",
    "navigateToLoginRequestUrl": true
  },
    "cache": {
        "cacheLocation": "localStorage"
    },
  "scopes": {
    "loginRequest": [ "openid", "profile", "Mail.Read", "offline_access", "user.read"]
  },
    "resources": {
      "todoListApi": {
        "resourceUri": "https://localhost:44351/api/todolist/",
        "resourceScope": "https://papayee008.onmicrosoft.com/papayee008/access_as_user"
      }
    }     
}
```

here is the config for Web Api:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "papayee008.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "ClientId": "28xxx12"
  },
  "https_port": 44351,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

But when I was trying to log in with my personal account, it throws me this error:
[image]

Comment: If you are working with AD, it cannot be your personal account. As your top screenshot shows that you are trying to use Azure AD.

Comment: ask this question on the samples issues page. It gets the attention of the developer

Comment: @KalyanKrishna I have done so, it is the only issue there, since then 2 days have passed, no update. I bet SOF has more popularity then there :)

Comment: hi @KarthikDV I use "common" as my tenant ID: ```common to sign in users with their work and school accounts or their personal Microsoft accounts``` It means I can use both organization accounts AND personal accounts. Unless Microsoft document has a mistake there.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be the use the same app/client id for both the SPA and the API. That is, instead of making separate app registrations for each component (as is suggested in the readme), simply make one app registration where you combine the steps for **Register the service app (TodoListAPI)** and **Register the client app (TodoListSPA)** in the readme of the sample repository.

EDIT: judging by the last screenshot, it might also be the case that your changes on "supported account types" on the AAD portal haven't taken effect yet. There's usually a few seconds delay, and if you tried to login with a personal account during that time, the issue in the screenshot would be expected.

Comment: thanks, I'm happy to use the same client ID for both front-end and backend. What are the differences between using same Client ID and using different client ID(otherwise the obvious differences e.g. register 1 app VS register 2 apps)

Comment: Previous Azure AD (v1.0) did not support using the same ID in different applications. This is changed in the the Azure AD v2.0 app model, as "applications" with multiple sub-components (for instance, lots of micro-services) became more common. One difference, or advantage, with sharing the client ID is that it makes [app provisioning and service principal creation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals) easier. Another difference (disadvantage) is that using the same client ID for *unrelated* applications might create a security risk

Comment: thanks @derisen, could you please help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524182/msal-net-no-account-or-login-hint-was-passed-to-the-acquiretokensilent-call