# MSAL.Net No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I have seen many same or similar questions, and tried all their answers if there was one, but none of those works for me.

I'm using [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnetcore-webapi) from Microsoft's Github account as my project base.

It works well for just signing in users.

The project has 1 WebApi, 1 Angular App.

Then I followed this [Microsoft example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph) to add code to call Graph API.
Here is the controller code:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BillsController : ControllerBase
{
    static readonly string[] scopeRequiredByApi = new string[] { "access_as_user" };
    readonly ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition;
    readonly WebOptions webOptions;

    public BillsController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition,
                          IOptions<WebOptions> webOptionValue)
    {
        this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        this.webOptions = webOptionValue.Value;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { Constants.ScopeUserRead, Constants.ScopeMailRead })]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
    {
        HttpContext.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(scopeRequiredByApi);

        var subject = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            // Initialize the GraphServiceClient. 
            Graph::GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient(new[] { Constants.ScopeUserRead, Constants.ScopeMailRead });

            var me = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            // Get user photo
            var messages = await graphClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().GetAsync();
            subject = messages.First().Subject;
            return Ok(subject);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private Graph::GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient(string[] scopes)
    {
        return GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(async () =>
        {
            string result = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
            return result;
        }, webOptions.GraphApiUrl);
    }
}
```

For Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Setting configuration for protected web api
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration);

        services.AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { Constants.ScopeUserRead, Constants.ScopeMailRead })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddGraphService(Configuration);

        // Creating policies that wraps the authorization requirements
        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));

        services.AddControllers();

        // Allowing CORS for all domains and methods for the purpose of sample
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("default", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // Since IdentityModel version 5.2.1 (or since Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer version 2.2.0),
            // Personal Identifiable Information is not written to the logs by default, to be compliant with GDPR.
            // For debugging/development purposes, one can enable additional detail in exceptions by setting IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII to true.
            // Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");

        app.UseCors("default");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

On the Angular App, I added one button to call this Profile() controller action.

todo-view.component.ts

```
  getEmails(): void {
    this.service.getEmails().subscribe({
      next: (emails: any) => {
        alert(emails);
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.log("error happened~!");
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

todo-view.component.html

```
<button (click)="getEmails();">Get Emails</button>
```

[image]

---

I added the below code into my Startup.cs and removed the AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi.
    services.AddProtectedWebApiCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration).AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

Now it throws me a different error message:

[image]

Comment: Franva, Have you checked the recent issue thread and workaround (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/314) for this?

Comment: thanks @Dev in that issue, the solution is to use ```[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" })]``` which I have done in my solution. Have you seen any other workaround?

Comment: You're welcome @Franva. Glad that already you're using the solution. Whenever i see any alternate workaround, i can able to provide an update.

Comment: sorry @Dev I think I caused some miscommunication. I wanted to say that by using the ```[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" })]`` it does not solve my problem. the error is still there.

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue in my react app. On the initial authentication it puts a token in the cache (sql) and it works fine for the life of the token. If the token expires, it gets removed from the cache and I get the "No Account or Login hint" error. AuthorizeForScopes is for returning views (MVC) and will not work if calling an API (mine is a core 3.1 api) so i'm not sure what to do as that seems to be the general recommendation. Have you found any answers to this?

Comment: @Seth nope, it seems that the MSAL.net is still at its early stage. I just dropped that idea.

Comment: @Franva I was actually able to get this working by changing some things in the startup configuration. I'll post my solution below.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue with a react app. Since the AuthorizeForScopes is for returning views, it does not work for API solutions. I was able to add some configuration options to get it working.

The first thing I did was use a SQL cache. This helped stop the "No login hint" error when the site restarted. After that, the token would work fine until timeout, after which the token would get removed from the cache and the error would reappear.

For that, I started looking at the configuration settings. I changed my configuration to the following.

```
services
    .AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi(new string[] { "User.Read" }, idOps =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", idOps);
        idOps.SaveTokens = true;
        idOps.RefreshOnIssuerKeyNotFound = true;
        idOps.SingletonTokenAcquisition = true;
        idOps.UseTokenLifetime = true;
    },
    ops => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", ops))
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches()
    .AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
    {
        options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Site_DbContext");
        options.SchemaName = "dbo";
        options.TableName = "_TokenCache";
    });
```

I haven't done much testing on it to find out the magic combination, but the sweet spot seems to be `SingletonTokenAcquisition`. With that set, it seems to be behaving like a hybrid cache. When first set, it pulls the token into memory and holds it so if it is removed from the database cache, it still has access to it.

The other settings may be necessary for the refreshing but I haven't tested that yet.

The one thing I did notice is the token doesn't get added back to the SQL cache until it refreshes so if something happens where the token is removed and the site goes down clearing the memory, the error may reappear, but this is the best solution I found so far. I was able to have my SPA running for 24 hours and was still able to pull new data.